# Subqueries SQL Lesson

Tags: sql

I try to answer this question : -- Query the users (userId) who are the authors of the most occuring tag in the tags table.

[image: Screenshot of my table here.]

I found that the most occurring tag in a first query is "Getdvd" which occurs 33 times.

Could you help me find the Users who write this tag 33 times? How to build it in 1 single query?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is all about sets.  You need a subquery to get the most common tag from the set of tags.

```
           SELECT tag FROM tag GROUP BY tag ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then you need to find the authors using that tag

```
SELECT userID, tag, COUNT(*) uses 
  FROM tag
 WHERE tag IN (
           SELECT tag FROM tag GROUP BY tag ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
        )
 GROUP BY userId, tag
```

And, if you want the top ten tags change `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming SQL Server

First you need to find the most used tag.  You get the list of most used tags by grouping by them and using an aggregate function

```
SELECT TAG, COUNT(*) AS TAG_COUNT
FROM SOME_TABLE_YOU_DIDNT_NAME
GROUP BY TAG
```

That gives the tag counts to get the most used take the first after ordering

```
SELECT TOP 1 TAG
FROM SOME_TABLE_YOU_DIDNT_NAME
GROUP BY TAG
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Now we know the users we care about -- select the users that use that tag

```
SELECT userid 
FROM SOME_TABLE_YOU_DIDNT_NAME
WHERE TAG = (
     SELECT TOP 1 TAG
     FROM SOME_TABLE_YOU_DIDNT_NAME
     GROUP BY TAG
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
```

You could also use a windowing function to solve this without a subquery -- but you said you wanted a subquery in the subject -- so I did it this way.